# How to make playback button using html5?

Tags: javascript, html

Could any one show me the concept for playback button with simple animation in HTML5 canvas ?

It auto comes back if reach the limit area, but how can i control it by button ? 
Thank you so much.

For ex 1

```js
var context;

function setupAnimCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('assignmenttwoCanvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //setInterval('draw();', 20); //don't use this
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(e) {
            draw();          //use this instead..
        }
        img.src = '../images/dragon.png';
        //animation();
        draw(); //as we don't have an image to load, call here
                //remove when image is used instead
    }
}
var startPos = [500, 500];
var endPos = [0, 0];
var dx = -3, dy = -3;
var x = startPos[0], y = startPos[1];

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    //drawBackground();
    //ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20); //for demo as no image
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    
    if (x < endPos[0] || x > startPos[0] ||
        y < endPos[1] || y > startPos[1] ) {
        dx = -dx;
        dy = -dy;
    }
    //moveit();
    setTimeout(draw, 16);
}
setupAnimCanvas();
```

```html
<canvas id="assignmenttwoCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it.

**[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/03122qhh/)**

it will trigger reverse if you click the button

```js
var context;
var startPos = [500, 500];
var endPos = [0, 0];
var dx = -3, dy = -3;
var x = startPos[0], y = startPos[1];

function reverse(){
  
   dx = -dx;
   dy = -dy;
}

function setupAnimCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('assignmenttwoCanvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //setInterval('draw();', 20); //don't use this
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(e) {
            draw();          //use this instead..
        }
        img.src = '../images/dragon.png';
        //animation();
        draw(); //as we don't have an image to load, call here
                //remove when image is used instead
    }
}



function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    //drawBackground();
    //ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20); //for demo as no image
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    
    if (x < endPos[0] || x > startPos[0] ||
        y < endPos[1] || y > startPos[1] ) {
        dx = -dx;
        dy = -dy;
    }
    //moveit();
    setTimeout(draw, 16);
}
setupAnimCanvas();
```

```html
<canvas id="assignmenttwoCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<button id="reverse" onclick=reverse()>Reverse</button>
```

Comment: hi Dyrandz :D yay, i got it , i did same way as 1st your way ! thank you so much ! i will mark now. Could you show me where is mark button ?